# IMEX=1 and TypeGuessRows=0 is not working for ZipCode

Tags: excel, import

I've read dozen's of posts on this, but I can't get this to work.
I am importing a spreadsheet of addresses.  Zip codes column contains a mix of 5 digit zips, 9 digit zips, and 5-4 zips (5 digits, dash, and 4 digits).  (sorry I am at the mercy of users and this is not something I can control).

But no matter what I do, I can't get them all to import through OLEDB.  The 5-4 area always imported as null.

In HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE[Wow6432Node]Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\

```
ExcelImportMixedTypes=Text

TypeGuessRows=0
```

I've tried both 32 bit mode and 64 bit mode.
The input spreadsheets are .XLS format (sorry, I am at the mercy of users I cannot force them to upgrade).

Here is my connection string.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strServerFileName + ";Mode=Read;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1
```

I will gladly post spreadsheet if that helps.

OLEDB from my experience is EXTREMELY unreliable.  Is there another way to import Excel sheets that works reliably?

Answer (score 4):

I'm also having trouble getting this to work in Linked Tables in Access that point to Excel workbooks. However, I did get it to work in VBScript. I think you need to use this key instead if you are using ACE:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows
```

This points to the same key (change one and the other changes also):

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows
```

Hopefully that helps...

Answer (score 2):

The connection string you have posted is for .xlsx files and not for .xls ones. Try adapting [this version](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/excel-97-2003-xls-files-with-ace-oledb-120/) instead:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myOldExcelFile.xls;
Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";
```

Comment: Makes no difference.

Comment: Can you make one of the rows with the 5-4 ZIP code be the very first row of data in the Excel sheet and see if that helps? If Excel is still guessing the data type then starting with a 5-4 ZIP code should get the column treated as text